# Python PIL.Image.tobytes() gives invalid bytes for image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, bytesio, image-file

When I run this pillow code:

```py
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(BytesIO(some_bytes))
resized = image.resize((44, 44))
with open('filename.png', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(resized.tobytes())
```

No errors occur, but when I go to the file 'filename.png', my computer or any other software can't show the file, presumably because the bytes are invalid. Why is this so?

`resized.tobytes()` seems to return bytes, so I'm not sure why the picture's bytes are invalid. When I just write my normal bytes to filename.png it works, so that isn't invalid. Only the resized ones are.

Why is this so and how can I fix it?

Comment: Method `Image.tobytes` returns the raw image data from the internal storage. For compressed image data (e.g. PNG, JPEG) use save(), with a BytesIO parameter for in-memory data.

Comment: @JasonYang it worked, thank you!

Comment: Just use `resized.save('result.png')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Jason Yang in comments -

> Method `Image.tobytes` returns the raw image data from the internal storage. For compressed image data (e.g. PNG, JPEG) use save(), with a BytesIO parameter for in-memory data.